# Android Remote Desktop thru Wifi Only

Tags: remote-access

I need a remote desktop solution, where it doesn't need an internet connection and I could see the desktop. So:

- TeamViewer is not an option as it needs an Internet connection
- Unified Remote is not an option as I cannot see my desktop
- Same as Gmote

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to control your PC _from_ your Android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) on your PC, then open it (doesn't require net connection)
2. Connect your phone to the Wi-Fi network created by Connectify
3. Use a Remote Desktop app to connect to your PC's IP address

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking for a remote desktop solution that allows you to view/control your desktop/laptop from your Android mobile device over local wireless network, the answer is: Any RDP/VNC app.

Personally I use [PocketCloud](http://www.pocketcloud.com/) by Wyse. It supports both RDP (Microsoft Windows, built into the OS) and VNC (cross platform, if you have a Linux computer or Apple toy you want to view/control, or you prefer VNC on Windows) protocols.

Either RDP or VNC will work over a local network and, if you have proper firewall configuration and DNS setup, can be used over the public internet as well with reasonable security.

**VNC** requires a server to be running on the computer you wish to control. There are several "flavors" of VNC out there, and many of them are free (as in beer). Check out [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) for a pretty solid version.

**RDP** requires you to [enable Remote Desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/remote-desktop-connection-frequently-asked-questions) on your computer. In later version of Windows it is disabled by default.

The good thing about both these tools is that they are protocols, not confined app systems. As in, you don't need a Microsoft App on your Android tablet to view an RDP session, and you can install any VNC viewer app on your tablet/phone to view any type of VNC server. *(Note: With certain types of authentication in VNC, I've found some viewer apps don't work. Just find the right combination for what you need.)*

*If, however, you're asking something different, please clarify your question to indicate what it is you're actually asking.*

Answer (score 1):

there is a option of lan in teamviewer which u can use as an intranet (INTRA NET) and lan and doesnt require internet

Answer (score 0):

Try use PC Remote. You can view the desktop screen on phone and can also project mobile screen on computer. It has a lot of options to work with computer like PPT Tools, Power Tools, Multi-media Tools, Gaming Tools etc.
https://www.monect.com/pc-remote