# Remote control a computer without internet connection?

Tags: remote-control

Today I discovered one incredibly useful app that allows you to remote control your computer using your mobile phone. However, you need to be connected to the internet on both the phone and the computer and the problem is I only have a limited amount of data to use every month on my phone which would probably last me about a week if I were to use this app everyday. Is it possible to remote control a computer from far away without being connected to the Internet on the mobile phone? I really hope it is.

Comment: What OSes are involved on each end? If the mobile is running Android, take a look at my collection here: [Remote Droid 1: Control your Computer using your Droid](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc) But "from far away" your chances are fairly limited: how do you think the two could be connected without Internet? How should they communicate? It would work in a local network – but that contradicts your "from far away".

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41097/android-remote-desktop-thru-wifi-only

Comment: "Is it possible to remote control a computer from far away..." How far away do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

**No, there isn't.**

The internet is what allows computers to connect to each other when they are not on the same network. This would technically be possible if both devices were connected to the same network (most commonly the same router or ethernet hookup), but when your device is connected to a cellular connection, the internet it is the only way to connect your computer and phone.

Comment: Why not? As long as the computer itself is connected to e.g. the phone line, couldn't something like [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_(PBX)) be used?

Comment: @Izzy That's pretty cool. Didn't know about that. However, I don't personally know how you'd set that up.

Comment: Neither do I, or I had written an answer. I know it *is* possible, but I don't know all ingredients and the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The reason you need your *limited data* is because that is how the data gets transferred from one device to another. Through internet. In order to send commands (which are basically data packages) to a device, you have to have a connection with that device. That connection is internet. There are other forms of data transfer methods of course (i.e. radiowaves) however that is no use in this case.

Comment: One could use SMS if there's something like [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_(PBX)) available on the computer to receive and interprete them. OP didn't specify what exactly is to be "remote controlled". Simple actions could be performed this way like by "voice actions" of something like Alexa – and could even give feedback by returning an SMS, or playing TTS via a phone menu ;)